# how to read ssh output from 'last' and 'who' command

Tags: ssh, raspbian, sshd, last, who

I have just used the command 'last' to see who has logged into my server.

I am unsure how to read some of the output, particularly in Column 2 where it states `pts/l` and `:0`.

Instead of spoon feeding me the answer, could you point me in the direction of a good source or pdf's to read in order to become more familiar with this query and general ssh queries.

www.digitalocean.com has been useful up to this point.

Thanks guys( and girls).

Comment: Usually, good start is opening manual page for the respective commands (writing `man last` and `man who` in your terminal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pts/1` is your pseudoterminal. A pseudoterminal provides processes with an interface that is identical to that of a real terminal.

http://linux.die.net/man/4/pts

`:0` is your X11 Display

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System